# Is there any way to replace "|" (L) character to "I" (i) with notepad++?

Tags: windows, notepad++

How to replace any `l` (upper/lowercase "L") to `I` (upper/lower case "i") from any word found lowercase or uppercase?
EX:

```
MAN SNORlNG
```

should be

```
MAN SNORING
```

or

```
lt's there...
```

should be

```
It's there
```

Comment: What do you want? It seems that your question means `L` to `I` & `l` to `i`? But your example means `l` to `I`...

Answer (score 1):

Find & Replace (`Ctrl + H`) should suffice, no?

You can even use [regular expressions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions).

Comment: On the "Replace" menu, be sure to check "Match case" (and uncheck "Match whole word only").